# Android application with two packages

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, android-manifest, android-package-managers

I do an application in two versions: premium and free. Now for me the functional of premium version works after verification of:

```
  if (isPremiumVersion){
     //to do premium fuctions
  }.
```

But I do not think that it is good tone. How is it possible to divide these two versions, that they were independent of each other? Only at the start of application to do verification, and then already, for example, to start the certain manifest file with a certain package, and classes. Unfortunately, does not turn out to find material, how more correct to do it.

Comment: What you want is not possible in Android. Each APK is tied to a single package and built with a single manifest - you cannot change these or switch to an an alternative at runtime within the same APK. You either need to keep doing the check you are already doing or separate the verisons into two APKs, as mixel indicates.

Comment: @adelphus Totally agree. I did not notice that question is about runtime selection of manifest and classes. But the only right way is to go with product flavors and separate application to two different apks.

Comment: Yeah, I wanted to make it clear that your solution creates separate APKs (which may not be obvious to some). I would slightly counter the "only right way..." statement. The overhead of having to manage two build configurations (and APKs) might be too much when compared to a simple runtime check. It all depends on the App...

Comment: @adelphus Yes, if premium features become accessible by in-app purchase then there should be runtime check not product flavors.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is [Product flavors](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Product-flavors).

You can define them in `build.gradle`:

```
android {
    ....

    productFlavors {
        free {
            applicationId 'com.myapp.free'
        }

        premium {
            applicationId 'com.myapp.premium'
        }
    }
}
```

For each product flavor you can create it's own source set by creating directory with name of flavor in app `src` directory so your app structure will be like:

```
src/
  main/
  free/
  premium/
```

You can add customized `AndroidManifest.xml`, resources and sources in flavor source sets and they will be merged with `main` source set.

You should carefully read official documentation at link I mentioned above. There much more possibilities and details then I described here.